# ReadDirectoryChangesW rejecting HANDLE accepted by CreateIoCompletionPort

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm adding functionality to my (Qt-based) application to monitor an arbitrary folder on my Windows system for *any* activity recursively (something the Qt variant QFileSystemWatcher lacks).  After opening the folder with **CreatFileW()**, I create a completion port to receive the overlapped I/O, and then I queue a read using **ReadDirectoryChangesW()**.

I have placed all of this in the following "simple" Win32 console application to demonstrate (note that the "stdafx.h" header has been modified to include "windows.h", but is otherwise as the Visual Studio 2013 IDE generated it):

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#define MAX_BUFFER 4096

struct ThreadData
{;
    DWORD           winerr;
    HANDLE          handle;
    unsigned int    flags;
    int             recursive;
    HANDLE          completion_port;
    CHAR            buffer[MAX_BUFFER];
    DWORD           buffer_len;
    OVERLAPPED      overlapped;
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    DWORD winerr;
    ThreadData td;

    td.flags = FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME|
               FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_DIR_NAME|
               FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_ATTRIBUTES|
               FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SIZE|
               FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE|
               FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_ACCESS|
               FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_CREATION|
               FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SECURITY;
    td.recursive = 1;
    td.completion_port = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    td.handle = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;

    td.handle = CreateFileW(L"J:\\Font",         // arbitrary folder
                            FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY, // required
                            FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
                            NULL,
                            OPEN_EXISTING,
                            // Use FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED for asynchronous operation with ReadDirectoryChangesW.
                            FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
                            NULL);

    if(td.handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        winerr = GetLastError();
        CloseHandle(td->handle);
        return 0;
    }

    td.completion_port = CreateIoCompletionPort(td.handle,
                                                td.completion_port,
                                                (ULONG_PTR)td,
                                                0);    // max num processors
    if(td.completion_port == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        winerr = GetLastError();
        CloseHandle(td.completion_port);
        CloseHandle(td.handle);
        return 0;
    }

    BOOL rdc = ReadDirectoryChangesW(td.handle,
                                     td.buffer,    // read results
                                     MAX_BUFFER,
                                     td.recursive, // watch subdirectories
                                     // NOTE: At least one flag is required!
                                     td.flags,     // see Notify Filters below
                                     &td.buffer_len,
                                     &td.overlapped,
                                     NULL);         // completion routine
    if(rdc == 0)
    {
        winerr = GetLastError();     // "The handle is invalid. (0x6)"
        CloseHandle(td.completion_port);
        CloseHandle(td.handle);
        return 0;
    }

    // Launch thread here to handle completions and trigger new ones
    ...

    // Clean up when the thread is done
    CloseHandle(td.completion_port);
    CloseHandle(td.handle);

    return 0;
}
```

The thing to note about this code is that it is modeled after a Python module ("watcher"), written in C, that provides similar functionality to a Python environment.  I've used it in Python, and it works as expected with all of the same settings in this C++ fragment.

In the above code, **CreateIoCompletionPort()** accepts the HANDLE generated by **CreateFileW()**, but **ReadDirectoryChangesW()** does not.  It returns 0, and **GetLastError()** is returning "The handle is invalid. (0x6)".  I've tried this under both 32- and 64-bit compiles, just in case that made any difference (I was using the 64-bit version of Python).  Also, the directory specified doesn't appear to matter: All directories I specify produce the same result, which suggests it's a problem with the settings somewhere.

Is there something in the **CreateFileW()** call that might cause the HANDLE to be valid for generating a completion port, but would give the **ReadDirectoryChangesW()** function heartburn?

Comment: Your `OVERLAPPED` structure looks to be uninitialized.

Answer (score 3):

You are not initializing the I/O Completion Port correctly, and you are not initializing the `OVERLAPPED` structure at all.  `ReadDirectoryChangesW()` is failing because the `OVERLAPPED::hEvent` field contains an invalid event object handle.  That is the invalid handle that the error code is referring to, not the directory handle.

Try this instead:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#define MAX_BUFFER 4096

struct ThreadData
{
    DWORD           winerr;
    HANDLE          handle;
    DWORD           flags;
    BOOL            recursive;
    HANDLE          completion_port;
    CHAR            buffer[MAX_BUFFER];
    DWORD           buffer_len;
    OVERLAPPED      overlapped;
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    DWORD winerr;
    ThreadData td;

    td.flags = FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME|
               FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_DIR_NAME|
               FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_ATTRIBUTES|
               FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SIZE|
               FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE|
               FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_ACCESS|
               FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_CREATION|
               FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SECURITY;
    td.recursive = TRUE;
    td.completion_port = NULL;
    td.handle = CreateFileW(L"J:\\Font",         // arbitrary folder
                            FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY, // required
                            FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
                            NULL,
                            OPEN_EXISTING,
                            // Use FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED for asynchronous operation with ReadDirectoryChangesW.
                            FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
                            NULL);

    if(td.handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        winerr = GetLastError();
        return 0;
    }

    td.completion_port = CreateIoCompletionPort(td.handle,
                                                NULL,
                                                (ULONG_PTR)&td,
                                                0);    // max num processors
    if(td.completion_port == NULL)
    {
        winerr = GetLastError();
        CloseHandle(td.handle);
        return 0;
    }

    ZeroMemory(&td.overlapped, sizeof(td.overlapped)); // <-- add this!

    // required if the thread uses GetOverlappedResult()...
    // optional if the thread uses GetQueuedCompletionStatus()...
    /*
    td.overlapped.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
    if(td.overlapped.hEvent == NULL)
    {
        winerr = GetLastError();
        CloseHandle(td.completion_port);
        CloseHandle(td.handle);
        return 0;
    }
    */

    BOOL rdc = ReadDirectoryChangesW(td.handle,
                                     td.buffer,    // read results
                                     MAX_BUFFER,
                                     td.recursive, // watch subdirectories
                                     // NOTE: At least one flag is required!
                                     td.flags,     // see Notify Filters below
                                     &td.buffer_len,
                                     &td.overlapped,
                                     NULL);         // completion routine
    if(rdc == FALSE)
    {
        winerr = GetLastError();
        //CloseHandle(td.overlapped.hEvent);
        CloseHandle(td.completion_port);
        CloseHandle(td.handle);
        return 0;
    }

    // Launch thread here to handle completions and trigger new ones
    ...

    // Clean up when the thread is done
    //CloseHandle(td.overlapped.hEvent);
    CloseHandle(td.completion_port);
    CloseHandle(td.handle);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Actually, providing an event object is not required.  Documentation says "The user must initialize this member either to zero or a valid event handle using the `CreateEvent` function before passing this structure to any overlapped functions."  So the error is not for lack of a valid event handle, but for passing an invalid (uninitialized) event handle.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Remy!  In line with what Ben just pointed out, the C code for the Python extension doesn't initialize the OVERLAPPED structure with a new event either, and yet it still works from Python.  However, a point I missed in that code is the allocation for the structure automatically zeros it out, which I guess I was missing.  Doing a memset on the ThreadData structure cleared the error, and the code works perfectly now!  That you both for the help.

Answer (score 1):

[CreateIoCompletionPort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363862.aspx) returns `NULL` on error, not `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`. So your first error is on this line:

```
 td.completion_port = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
```

It must be this instead:

```
 td.completion_port = NULL;
```

And this incorrect check:

```
if(td.completion_port == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
```

Must be this instead:

```
if(td.completion_port == NULL)
```

You get `NULL` in `td.completion_port` after `CreateIoCompletionPort` because the initial value of `td.completion_port` is invalid. Also, you are incorrectly handling the error case (say try close invalid handles).

Comment: Oops.  Absolutely, Remy.  I missed that detail in the MSDN docs.  Thanks for pointing it out.